# Terminal output simultaneous redirection to a file

Tags: bash, files, io-redirection

I couldn't get the exact command on how to redirect the output of a running command to a filename.

I used below command but this is not what I wanted. It just store the value of the command to a filename.

```
command |& tee FILENAME
```

What I need is that while the command is running it is showing on screen that process is ongoing and also store the output to a filename so that later I can manipulate the output.

Comment: At least under normal circumstances `cmd |& tee FILENAME` should do exactly what you are asking for. So I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

don't nedd the '&' character

```
root@h2g2w lib]# echo toto | tee titi      
toto
[root@h2g2w lib]# cat titi
toto
[root@h2g2w lib]#
```

Comment: it still doesnt work. I have to do 'cat' on  the file before it will show on screen. I want to show it onscreen and store it. But it seems example above will really show on screen because of echo command, what if not "echo" command.

Comment: then explain with full example of real command & output using | tail ...  and explain what you would have instead of the output

Answer (score 0):

Use an improved version of your command:

```
command | tee -a FILENAME
```

- `tee`: read from standard input and write to standard output and files
- `-a`: append to the given FILEs, do not overwrite
- `|`: Pipe the results of command to `tee` programme